# Android view invisible while drag

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

What I want to achieve should be very easy, but I cant find any solitions for it.

I want to have a dragable button, which should be invisible while draging.
When the user starts draging this button, I want only the dragshadow of the button to be displayed.

So far I have have mutliple buttons with this `onTouch` function of their `OnTouchListener`

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    v.startDrag(null, new DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Now I need another method, where I can set my button visible again.
I already tried an `OnDragListener`, but this Listener only sets all buttons, but not the Button I actually dragged?

Maybe there is even another Approach without `setVisibility` and `DragShadowBuilder`?

**Edit:**

In [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) tutorial I found, that I can use `event.getlocalstate()` to in my `OnDragListener` to get the View that is beeing dragged. 
There I could set my View visible again.
The problem is, that this method returns `null` all the time.

**Edit 2:**

I created a new simple project containing only three buttons and a textview where the buttons can be dropped. I used the code from the tutorial, but it's still not working:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button1.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());
    button2.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());
    button3.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());

    TextView dropArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    dropArea.setOnDragListener(new MyOnDragListener());


}

private class MyOnDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:{
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                if (view == null){
                    Log.e("SORRY", "NO VIEW!");
                }else{
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

private class MyOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.startDrag(null, new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason why `event.getLocalState()` returns `null` is because you forgot to pass your view as a local state parameter while calling `startDrag` method.

You should have

`v.startDrag(null, new DragShadowBuilder(v), v, 0);`

instead of

`v.startDrag(null, new DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);`

You will now be able to retrieve your view and restore its visibility ;)

Comment: I changed my code into first one `v.startDrag(null, new DragShadowBuilder(v), v, 0);`. but still getLocalState() returns null.

Comment: `ClipData dragData = new ClipData(view.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
  View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                view.startDragAndDrop(dragData, myShadow, view, 0);
            } else {
                view.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, view, 0);
            }`                                                                                                          and it worked.

Comment: 2 Changes are required :

1.  Condition to Check the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
2.  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {}

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you set the visibility of the view when the touch is release ?
For that, you just have to modify your code this way :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        v.startDrag(null, new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      /* ENTER YOUR CODE HERE */
      /* For example : 
         button.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
      */
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if your code was correct, this wouldn't work.  When `startDrag` is called, an `ACTION_CANCEL` event is received and no further `MotionEvents` will be received.

Comment: I commented that in 2015 and I haven't done any mobile development since then. What should be changed so that this answer is valid?

Answer (score 0):

2 Changes are required :

1. Condition to Check the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
2. if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

   ```
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) view.getTag());
           String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
           ClipData data = new ClipData(view.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
           DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);


           if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
               view.startDragAndDrop(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
           } else {
               view.startDrag(data, //data to be dragged
                       shadowBuilder, //drag shadow
                       view, //local data about the drag and drop operation
                       0);  //no needed flags
           }

           view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           return true;
       }else {
           return false;
       }
   ```